# JQuery how to append on the same place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coffeescript, transform

so in a project i need to append a few elements with jquery. I am using the `.append()` function, an it works fine, but what i need to really do is append the elements in the same place every time, and not one after the other.

[image]

as you can see i need the secon element (yellow one) - and the next ones - to be **appended** but every time on the same place, not dependent on the before elements positions.

sorry for bad english.

Comment: can you please add the code to your question?

Comment: Use `css` and set your elements with `position:absolute;` and `z-index: jQuery.count.elements`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @darklightcode mentioned, you should solve this by using CSS.
Add `position: relative` rule to the Parent element. Then, add `position: absolute` to Child elements, that you are appending to. The easiest way would be to give each element, that you are adding the same class, that has this rule: `position: absolute`.

You won't need to specify `z-index` for each added element, because by default the last added will be visible on top of all other elements.

It can look like this:
HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child green"></div>
  <div class="child yellow"></div>
  <div class="child red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: @newbie nice catch, i forgot about the autoincrement of `z-index`. One less script to worry about.